# Enabling maven surefire forkCount fails in at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:581)

Tags: java, maven, fork, maven-surefire-plugin

Hello everybody :) I am interested in running my maven tests in 8 forks because I have thousands of tests and it takes literally more than 6h hours to run them sequentially. I have therefore introduced the following configuration:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <excludedGroups>${it.test.excludedGroups}</excludedGroups>
              <groups>${it.test.includedGroups}</groups>
              <forkCount>8</forkCount>
              <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
              <reportsDirectory>ghatarget/failsafe-reports/${surefire.forkNumber}</reportsDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
```

However, when checking my maven tests I see the following error in every individual test but it doesnt log any meaningful error explaining why this error is being thrown:

```
at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.execute(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:228)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:131)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:456)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:595)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:581)
```

Would anyone maybe have an idea? I am really clueless as to what I am doing wrong. Could it been that I need some additional configuration? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Which version of maven-failsafe-plugin do you use? Why have you changed `<reportsDirectory>`??? stick with the conventions...

Comment: @khmarbaise changed the reportsDirectory because as said I dont wanna use the target folder but a custom output folder